# Error in calling db context in ASP. NET application [VISUAL STUDIO 2012]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I have just started learning ASP.Net and got stuck in my first application with ADO. NET entity model. I have created a small table contact_master(id, name, phone, email) and trying to insert a row in the table using the entity. But I get below error,

> ASP .NET 'contactEntities' does not contain a definition for
>   'contact_masters' and no extension method 'contact_masters' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'contactEntities' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is the code for page1.aspx.cs file.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            contactEntities obj = new contactEntities();
            contact_master c = new contact_master();

            c.email = "test@test.com";
            c.name = "sdsd";
            c.phone = "543634";
            obj.contact_masters.save(c);
        }
    }
```

Below is how my solution explorer looks like

[image]

"obj.contact_masters.save(c);" contains the error :( Apologies if I messed up in terminologies.

Comment: How did you create the `contactEntities` class and what does it look like?

Comment: @GertArnold I might sound an idiot but it was created Using Entity data model Wizard. It should contain the local database string. I did the same as > https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc-classic/schedule/how-to/create-adonet-entity-data-model